# No Class Def Found Error when executing jar commans line

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, classpath

I was trying to execute a JAR that has all the dependecies copied under JAR lib folder. But when I try executing the JAR command line I was getting below error

```
at com.abc<clinit>(abc.java:33)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
```

Here is my JAR structure:

abc.jar 
---lib\all dependency libraries 
---com\abc 
---META-INF

here is my pom.xml

```
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
              <mainClass>com.main.class</mainClass>
              <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

java cannot load embedded jars in a jar. You need a uber-jar class-loader for this.

The manifest entry for the classpath will look for the classpath `lib` outside the jar, not inside.

Usual strategies are to expand all dependency jars into one new jar, so that all classes are in the same jar file. This has drawbacks, as META-INF information is overwritten.

The other common and even working strategy is the already mentioned alternative classloader. There are some available for maven.

I have used one-jar, and it works pretty well. If you use spring-boot, there is the spring-boot classloader which will do the same for you.

One-jar seems abandoned nowadays, you can find it here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jolira/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4, and these people have some kind of tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/

Spring Boot uses the spring-boot-loader: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html

The apache shade plugin for maven seems to be pretty popular, but I havn't used that so far. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html